# C (Console calculator) still processing if statement when previously set to false

Tags: c

Im a beginner to the C language and taking a course at school. Well I'm working on a project, where we have to make a console calculator. I completed, the assignment and it works fine, but I wanted to add another little snippet of "if valid equation then print out" instead of constantly having to type it in each case. 
It seems to work, when the "ValidEqn" does equal one. But when an invalid equation is set and it defaults to the "default:" case, and the "ValidEqn" is set to "0", it still process the "printf" inbetween the if statement. Could someone please explain why? and what flaws are in my code. I'd highly appreciate it.

```
        #include <stdio.h>

        int main(void)
        {

            float num1, num2, answer = 0.0f;
            char op;
            int ValidEqn = 1;

            printf("Operators: ( +, -, * or x, / or \ or %)\n");
            printf("Instruction: Please enter a number, operator, number\n");
            printf("\nEquation: ");
            scanf("%f %c %f", &num1, &op, &num2);


            switch ( op ) 
            {

            case '*' :
            case 'x':
                answer = num1 * num2;
            break;

            case '+':
                answer = num1 + num2;
            break; 

            case '-':
                answer = num1 - num2;

            break;

            case '/' :
            case '\\':
            case '%':
                answer = num1 / num2;

            break;

            default:
                ValidEqn = 0;
                printf("You did not enter a proper equation");

            break;
            }

            if ( ValidEqn = 1 )
            {
                printf("The answer of %.0f %c %.0f is %.0f\n", num1, op, num2, answer);
            }


            return(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `==`, not `=`.  If you use `=`, you are modifying the variable and then testing whether the result is true or false.  Change it to:

```
if ( ValidEqn == 1 )
```

Or even better, since it's used as a boolean:

```
if ( ValidEqn )
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems typo about checking equality.

```
if ( ValidEqn = 1 )
```

Should be

```
if ( ValidEqn == 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your.....

```
  if ( ValidEqn = 1 )
                {
                    printf("The answer of %.0f %c %.0f is %.0f\n", num1, op, num2, answer);
                }
```

Should be...

```
if ( ValidEqn == 1 )
            {
                printf("The answer of %.0f %c %.0f is %.0f\n", num1, op, num2, answer);
            }
```

Refer this for further information....
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm